# How can we check whether block is enabled or disabled in .theme file?

Tags: 8, theming, blocks

I am displaying a block in twig and i am passing twig variable from `hook_preprocess_page`. But the issue when i disable the block from backend still its showing up in frontend. Im not able to get status of the block. Can anyone help me. Below is my code:

```
$lang_block = Block::load('dropdownlanguage');
  //if (!empty($lang_block)) {} also i tried.

  if (isset($lang_block)) {
    $content = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block')->view($lang_block);
      $variables['language_block'] = $content;
  }
```

In **.twig file** :

```
{%  if language_block %}
   {{ language_block }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ConfigEntityBase::status](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Config%21Entity%21ConfigEntityBase.php/function/ConfigEntityBase%3A%3Astatus/8.7.x):

```
if (isset($lang_block) && $lang_block->status()) {
  // block is enabled
}
```